# enable_if not able to speciialize a function for more than two cases

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have the following code to specialize the function start for the particular vehicle type in C++11:

```
template< typename Vehicle>

struct s{
    template< typename T = void>
    typename enable_if<is_same<Vehicle, Car>::value, T>::type start() {
        // body
    }

    template< typename T = void>
    typename enable_if<is_same<Vehicle, Bike>::value, T>::type start() {
       // body
    }

    template< typename T = void>
    typename enable_if<is_same<Vehicle, Scooter>::value, T>::type start() {
       // body
    }
};
int main() {
    s<Car>::start();
}
```

When I compile this it throws an error: `multiple overloads of 'start' instantiate to the same signature`

The thing is when I remove one of the specializations(say the scooter type), it compiles happily. Why is this happening and how can I resolve this issue ? Any leads would be appreciated .

Comment: Try: `template<typename V = Vehicle, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<V, Car>, int> = 0> void start() { ... }`.

Comment: I think this is what happens. When `s<Car>` is instantiated, the compiler notices that there are two overloads of `start` both with the return type of `typename enable_if<false, T>::type`. This happens before it gets to actually instantiating `start()` and discovering that those overloads result in substitution failure. Basically, SFINAE works on template parameters of the function it applies to; but not on template parameters of the enclosing class template.

Comment: @Evg This results in an error `no matching member function for call to 'start'`

Comment: @Evg might have meant `template<typename T = void, typename V = Vehicle> static std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<V, Car>, T> start() { }`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PncMoe5hn)

Comment: You put three tags of C++ versions (11, 14 and 17). Which one applies? If you can use C++17, I would suggest to use `if constexpr` inside a single template `start` method. I generally found it much more convenient and safe than a bunch of `std::enable_if`.

Comment: C++11 applies here

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Great! This worked. Can you explain why this works and why the above implementations fail ?

Comment: Like I said, here SFINAE is applied to the function template's own template parameters, not those of the enclosing class template. `std::is_same_v<V, Bike>` doesn't collapse to `true` or `false` at the time `s<Car>` is instantiated, because at that point it's not yet known what `V` is going to be. The caller could, in principle, write `s<Car>::start<void, Bike>()`